# How does $af\left(\frac{n}{b}\right) \leq cf(n)$ imply that $a^{i}f\left(\frac{n}{b^{i}}\right) \leq c^{i}f(n)$?

Tags: induction, computer-science, functional-inequalities

This is part of a proof for the third case in the Master Theorem in [CLRS], 3rd edition. $a\geq 1$, $b>1$ and $c<1$. Also, $f$ is a nonnegative function.

It makes sense for polynomial functions but I don't see how they generalized it. I tried mathematical induction but no luck. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I'll show you $i=2$, perhaps you can take it from there: $$a^2f(n/b^2) = a\cdot f((n/b)/b) \le acf(n/b).$$

Comment: Still lost. I don't see what happens to the 'a'. How does that first equality reduce the power of the a?

Comment: Oh man. I made a typo. I mean to put $a\cdot af((n/b)/b)$.

Comment: Thank you! Everything makes perfect sense now. I made that more difficult than it should have been. Note to self: don't forget to eat.

Answer (score 1):

*This is the outline -- to be perfectly formal, there would be annoying details or discussion about floors and ceilings to take care of, for instance, since $\frac{n}{b^i}$ is not an integer in general.*

**Assumption:**
for all $n$ greater than some constant $n_0$, we have
$$
af\left(\frac{n}{b}\right) \leq c f(n) \tag{$\dagger$}
$$

Then, iterate *(i.e., perform an induction in disguise)*:
$$\begin{align}
a^i f\left(\frac{n}{b^i}\right) &= a^{i-1}\cdot f\left(\frac{(n/b^{i-1})}{b}\right)
\operatorname*{\leq}_{(\dagger)} 
a^{i-1}\cdot c f\left(\frac{n}{b^{i-1}}\right)
= ca^{i-2}\cdot af\left(\frac{(n/b^{i-2})}{b}\right) \\
&\operatorname*{\leq}_{(\dagger)} 
ca^{i-2}\cdot c f\left(\frac{n}{b^{i-2}}\right)
= c^2a^{i-3}\cdot a f\left(\frac{(n/b^{i-3})}{b}\right) \\
&\vdots\\
&\operatorname*{\leq}_{(\dagger)} 
c^{i-1} a^0\cdot cf\left(\frac{n}{b^{0}}\right) = c^i f(n).
\end{align}$$